# How is the "jQuery" var a function and an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, when you use `jQuery('someDiv');`, it's a function, but you can also use `jQuery.ajax(...);`.

How is it possible?

Comment: See also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302428/what-does-jquery-actually-return

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions themselves are objects.

```
var x = function () {};
x.foo = "bar";

console.log(x.foo); // bar
```

**EDIT:**

To add onto this:

```
var x = function () {
    return 'foo';
};
x.bar = function () {
    return 'baz';
};
```

So now:

```
console.log(x()); // foo
console.log(x.bar()); // baz
```

Comment: Mother of god, I didn't know that o_O

Comment: Functions are first class citizens in JavaScript.

Comment: This is an excellent example of one of the beauties of JavaScript. It has its downsides, too (!), but certainly beauties as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the .ajax example is utilizing the jQuery plug-in architecture. I think the AJAX capabilities of jQuery are just one of the many plug-ins you could use.

The '$' that use see is also just a alias for calling the jQuery.

One last observation jQuery is defined as (from the jquery-1.4.2.js):

```
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
    },
```

and Ajax looks like:

```
jQuery.extend({
...some other goodness...
ajax: function( origSettings ) 
...more goodness...
});
```