# How would you define a type in typescript that's both an object and a function at the same time?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, prototype

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7223609/6224823) to the question `How is jQuery's $ a function and an object?`, it got me thinking. How would you define this kind of type in typescript?

In regular JS this is completely valid:

```
var f = function() { alert('yo'); }
f.foo = "bar";

alert(f.foo); // alerts "bar"
f();          // alerts "yo"
```

However in typescript, `f.foo` would throw an error, `Property 'foo' does not exist on type '() => void'`.

While you could achieve a similar result using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```
var f = function() { alert('yo'); }
f['foo'] = "bar";

alert(f['foo']); // alerts "bar"
f();          // alerts "yo"
```

This would entirely bypass the type system, and there for the type safety, of typescript.

Is there a way of implementing this type of functionality without violating the type safety of typescript?

Comment: Maybe you can find a hint in [DefinitelyTyped/types/jquery/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/924fafffc09cfeb0267573af2c847cdbfcfa464d/types/jquery/index.d.ts), I think they do exactly that, but I didn't take a closer look at it.

Comment: @t.niese They do, however that file is 8000 rows, and extracting the few rows that define this particular behavior is made even harder when i don't even know what I'm looking for.

Comment: But it is at least a starting point ;). Just in case that you do not get any answer that helps, you would at least have this link where you might find a solution. I would also need to look through the whole document to find that information, because I don't know it either.

Comment: @t.niese Yea, thank you. Lets hope I wont have to resort to that.

Comment: What kind of functionality do you want? Some sort of factory function like jQuery's `$` which gets a CSS selector and returns wrapped DOM objects with jQuery functions attached? It is not clear what kind of functionality do you want.

Comment: @Dmitry I don't really care for any of the implementation details, that I can do on my own. What I'm curious about is how you define a type in ts that's both an object and a function at the same time.

Comment: This question already has answers, but the [Object Types section of the TypeScript spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#13-object-types) has a bit about JQuery and how the interface both has properties and is callable like a function.

Comment: You really should think about separating code from data, not to mix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define this kind of type by specifying an invocation signature on an interface:

```
interface MyFoo {
    (): void;
    foo: string;
}
```

And you can initialize the object by casting the function to `any` before assigning it to the variable:

```
let f: MyFoo = function() { alert('yo'); } as any;
f.foo = 'bar';
x();
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20MyFoo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20f%3A%20MyFoo%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20alert('yo')%3B%20%7D%20as%20any%3B%0D%0Af.foo%20%3D%20%22bar%22%3B%0D%0Af()%3B)

---

As an aside, the `JQueryStatic` type (which is the type of the `$` variable) is defined similarly in the [JQuery defintions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/924fafffc09cfeb0267573af2c847cdbfcfa464d/types/jquery/index.d.ts):

```
interface JQueryStatic<TElement extends Node = HTMLElement> {
    ...
    Deferred: JQuery.DeferredStatic;
    ...
    (html: JQuery.htmlString, ownerDocument_attributes: Document | JQuery.PlainObject): JQuery<TElement>;
    ...
    (selector: JQuery.Selector, context: Element | Document | JQuery | undefined): JQuery<TElement>;
```

(Can't put the links inline, so here they are)

- [interface start](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/924fafffc09cfeb0267573af2c847cdbfcfa464d/types/jquery/index.d.ts#L43)
- [Deferred property](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/924fafffc09cfeb0267573af2c847cdbfcfa464d/types/jquery/index.d.ts#L53)
- [First invokable signature](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/924fafffc09cfeb0267573af2c847cdbfcfa464d/types/jquery/index.d.ts#L121)

However, this doesn't really help, as your question is also how to initialize a variable with this type. The JQuery library doesn't have that problem, because it isn't written in Typescript.

Comment: How would you use this interface?

Comment: @torazaburo To be fair, having to use `any` for what should be a straightforward initialization leaves me feeling slightly uncomfortable.

Comment: @ZevSpitz thank you. And I agree, having it use `any` feels dirty, but having the option of using interfaces instead of intersection types, kind of makes up for it in my opinion.

Comment: @Olian04 Why do you prefer an interface over an intersection type, aside from 1) any function being assignable to `Function`, not just a specific signature; and 2) the `foo` property is optional, and therefore might be `undefined` (as I noted in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861592/how-would-you-define-a-type-in-typescript-thats-both-an-object-and-a-function-a/45865475#comment78756353_45865270) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861592/how-would-you-define-a-type-in-typescript-thats-both-an-object-and-a-function-a/45865475#comment78756652_45865270)?

Comment: @ZevSpitz other than those two reasons, it's mostly personal preference. It feels more easily maintainable, and more self documenting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&` to define a variable with multiple types. It's called an "Intersection Type". More informations in the [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Here's how to use it in your example :

```
let f: Function & {foo?: String} = function() { alert('yo'); }
f.foo = "bar";

alert(f.foo); // alerts "bar"
f();          // alerts "yo"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20f%3A%20Function%20%26%20%7Bfoo%3F%3A%20String%7D%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%20alert('yo')%3B%20%7D%0D%0Af.foo%20%3D%20%22bar%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(f.foo)%3B%20%2F%2F%20alerts%20%22bar%22%0D%0Af()%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20alerts%20%22yo%22)

Here, the type of `f` is `Function & {foo?: String}` because it's both a `Function`, and also `{foo?: String}`. The `?` is required here, as you initialize it as only a `Function`, and only then you assign a value to `foo`.

You can see in the Playground that the code compiles, and even gives the same JavaScript code you started with, validating that this is the correct syntax.

Comment: Using `Function` allows any function signature to be assigned to `f`: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20f%3A%20Function%20%26%20%7B%20foo%3F%3A%20String%20%7D%20%3D%20(first%3A%20string%2C%20second%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20alert(first%20%2B%20second)%3B%20). AFAIK there is no way to specify a function type with a given signature, aside from an interface.

Comment: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20creator%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20f%3A%20Function%20%26%20%7B%20foo%3F%3A%20string%20%7D%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20alert('yo')%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20f.foo%20%3D%20%22bar%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20f%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(creator().foo.length)%3B).

Comment: Also, `foo` is typed as possibly undefined; it's not an issue here because Typescript's flow analysis sees the assignment for this particular object, and determines that `foo` is `string` and not `string | undefined`. Once outside the local context (e.g. if returned from a function), and using the `strictNullChecks` option, `foo` is treated as `string | undefined`. (playground link above).