# How does jQuerys $.each() work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks

Maybe a bad title, but this is my problem:
I'm building a framework to learn more about javascript. And I want to use ""jQuery"" style.

**How can I make a function where the `()` is optional?**

```
$("p").fadeOut(); //() is there
$.each(arr, function(k, v) {...}); //Dropped the (), but HOW?
```

This is what I have come up with, but it don't work:

```
$2DC = function(selector)
{
    return new function() {
        return {
            circle : function()
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}


$2DC("#id1"); //Work
$2DC("#id2").circle(); //Work
$2DC.circle(); //DONT WORK
```

Comment: Your title is confusing. I don't think `$.()` is even valid JavaScript.

Comment: duplicate of [How is the "jQuery" var a function and an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724784/how-is-the-jquery-var-a-function-and-an-object)

Comment: I you want to learn from jQuery, then I think it's best to have a look at the source code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`$` is really just an alias for the `jQuery` function.  You can call the function with:

`jQuery("p");` or `$("p");`

but remember, in JavaScript you can attach "stuff" directly to functions.

```
function foo(){
}
foo.blah = "hi";
foo.func = function() { alert("hi"); };

foo.func(); //alerts "hi"
```

This is how (conceptually) jQuery's `each` function is defined.

```
jQuery.each = function(someArr, callback) { ...
```

And so now `jQuery.each` is a function that can be called like this:

```
jQuery.each([1, 2, 3], function(i, val) {
});
```

or the more familiar

```
$.each([1, 2, 3], function(i, val) {
});
```

---

So for your particular case, to support:

```
$2DC.circle();
```

You'd have to add the `circle` function directly to `$2DC`:

```
$2DC.circle = function(){
   // code
};
```

Comment: Thanks! :) That was really easy... I learn a lot by building a framework.

Comment: @Sawny - sure thing.  JavaScript is a lot of fun

Answer (score 6):

Functions are objects in JavaScript.  As such, they can be used as variables, just like ints, strings, etc.

In your example, `$2DC` is a function that returns an object containing a `circle` function.

`$2DC.circle();` doesn't work as `circle` is only a property of the returned object, not of `$2DC` itself.

In the case of `$.each`, this works as `$` contains an `each` property.  Your `$2DC` can do that too.  Like this:

```
$2DC.circle = function(){
}
```

Now, `$2DC.circle();` will work.  So, as you see functions are objects, and as such can have properties just like other objects.

Comment: +1, even though you beat me out of an enlightened badge by 4 seconds :-)

Comment: @AdamRackis: I'm an answer ninja ^_^

Answer (score 1):

```
$2DC.circle(); //DONT WORK
```

This didn't work because $2DC do not have any function with name `circle`. It is just a function.

Where as `$2DC("#id2")` returns a new function containing object having `circle` function so `$2DC("#id2").circle();` works fine for you.

If you define

```
$2DC.circle = function(){

};
```

You can use `$2DC.circle();`

Answer (score 0):

The `$.each` method that you refer to is a property on the `$` function object.

The `$` object in jQuery is a function object and like any object in JavaScript, you can assign properties on the object.

Invoking the `$` function object acts as a constructor function and returns a new object instance created by the `jQuery.fn.init()` function. The prototype of `jQuery` is copied to `jQuery.fn.init` so that newly created object instances have access to the methods and plugins defined on `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Create your base function, then add methods to the function.

```
var f = function(text){
    alert(text);
}
f.fn1 = function(text){
    alert('fn:'+text);
}
f.fn2 = function(text){
    alert('fn2:'+text);
}

f('hi'); //hi;
f.fn1('hi'); //fn:hi;
f.fn2('hi'); //fn2:hi;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using something like this.

```
$.fn.each = function (otherparams);

$.each = function (collection, otherparams) {
  return $.fn.each.apply(collection, arguments.slice(1));
};
```

Adding each as a property of fn (which is just an alias for jQuery.prototype) means it's available as a method of each jQuery collection. The second bit of code means it can be passed in a collection as an argument instead.

[apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (and [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)) are some of the most useful features of javascript once you get used to them.

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this:

```
$2DC = (function(selector)
{
    return new function() {
        return {
            circle : function()
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

this way the $2DC is the object returned by the function and not the function itself.

Comment: to the guy who voted me down, you must be a real genius:
http://jsfiddle.net/andrepadez/Pdvju/

Comment: In this case `$2DC` is no longer a function, it's just a normal object.  `$2DC("#id1");` no longer works.  This is not what the OP wanted.  I down-voted you because of that, and because you didn't explain the code in your answer.

Comment: It's an object, that returns functions, just like jQuery!
try the fiddle then

Comment: `jQuery` is a function (which is an object).  It can be called like this: `jQuery('p')`.  In your answer, `$2DC` is just a normal object (not a function), so `$2DC('p')` does not work.

Comment: var jQuery = (function() { ... })( window );     this is the source of jQuery, want to argue some more?

Comment: Yes I do.  Check the [last line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L957): `return jQuery`.  This [refers to a function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L4) (which also happens to be named `jQuery`).  So jQuery is a function, not just a normal object.  In your example you're returning `new function()` which is an object.  jQuery is returning `function` which is a function.  Since jQuery is a function `$('p')` works.  In your case `$2DC('p')` doesn't work as it's just a normal object, not a function.

Comment: oh, yes... i forgot to include that detail. i'm sorry for that