# Create Canvas from image on javascript

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

I'm trying to learn manipulate image and canvas in javascript. I'm wondering why we can not do :

```
var urlimg='http://images.aviary.com/imagesv5/feather_default.jpg'; 
         var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
         var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
         var img = new Image();
         img.onload = function(){

         }
         img.src =urlimg ;
         can.width = img.width;
         can.height = img.height;
         ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
         $('#image1').attr('src', img.src);
```

And we have to do this :

```
var urlimg='http://images.aviary.com/imagesv5/feather_default.jpg'; 
         var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
         var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
         var img = new Image();
         img.onload = function(){
             can.width = img.width;
             can.height = img.height;
             ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
         }
         img.src =urlimg ;
         $('#image1').attr('src', img.src);
```

Is it due to time of image to load ?

Can I create a canvas from an existing object image ?

Thanks.

Comment: The image is loaded asynchronously after setting the src attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it due to time of image to load ?

Yes in part, but mostly because image loading is asynchronous so the next lines of code are executed right away *while* the image is loaded. To let you know an event is raised when it's done.

> Can I create a canvas from an existing object image ?

No (not directly), but you can draw the image onto a canvas to initialize it (as you already do):

```
ctx.drawImage(imageElement, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. Are there any difference between an image create like this : var=Image();   and $('#image1') in jquery where 'image1' is the id an img élement :<img ../>

Comment: @McbJam If you meant `var el = new Image()`, or in any case if you'd use `document.getElelementById()` they will return the element itself while jQuery's $ returns a *jQuery object* - kind of a wrapped set. See here for some more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302428/what-does-jquery-actually-return