# Redefining value of $ (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have created custom function with function name as `$`.

```
function $(){
    alert("Test");
}

jQuery(function(){
    alert($);
});
```

When I run this, I get the function body in the alert. But, when I debug this code, on keeping the break-point at `alert($)` in the browser(Chrome), I also get `alert("Test")` before the function body.

The same behavior is reproducible on the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/8ML9d/).

Can someone explain this behavior?

[image]

Comment: i see no `alert("Test")`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `I also get alert("Test") before the function body` ?? If you mean an alert with _Test_ shows, it doesn't for me.

Comment: Please see the screenshot attached.

Comment: @wizkid I see. Are you by any chance invoking the `$` function in the console or something? This seems pretty weird.

Comment: Following your edit, i better understood what you mean, this is not expected behaviour

Comment: And if you rename it to other than `$`, it works fine.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. What give you console.log($);  ?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302428/what-does-jquery-actually-return

Answer (score 5):

You have a function named `$`. When executing `alert($)` you are effectively telling browser to show function $ in the alert window, which it does. `$` is not specific here, same will work with `abc` function:

```
function abc(){
    alert("Test");
}
jQuery(function(){
    alert(abc);
});
```

If done like this:

```
function abc(){
    alert("Test");
}
jQuery(function(){
    alert(abc());
});
```

It will first run `abc()` and display "Test", then it will display the result of `abc()`, which is `undefined`.