# How can I focus on a selectize select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

Focusing on a select box (that has selectize enabled) does not focus on the selectized input box:

```
$('.someclass select').focus();
```

Focusing on selectize's own inout box doesn't seem to work either:

```
$('.someclass input').focus();
```

The [Selectize docs](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md) mentions `focus` but that doesn't seem to work either. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Rt8X/43/):

```
var selectized = $('#selectize').selectize();
selectized.focus();
```

I would expect the carat `|` to be ready and typing to immediately go into the box.

How can I focus on a selectize select box from JavaScript, so a user can type into it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use:

```
selectized[0].selectize.focus();
```

Comment: This worked for me, .click() in the accepted answer did not.

Comment: @mike-c This is the option provided in the Selectize API.  However it is a bit confusing how you access these methods.

https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_other

Comment: I've changed the answer to this as it's the proper way to do things according to the selectize authors, as you mention,

Answer (score 7):

One way which appears to work is to call `click()` instead of `focus()`:

```
$('.someclass input').click();
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('.someclass input')` returns a jquery object (wrapped set - see [What does jquery $ actually return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302428/what-does-jquery-actually-return)).  You don't want the wrapped set, you want the first element in the set that matches the selector.

Try `$('.someclass input')[0].selectize.focus();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For me `$('.someclass input').focus()` did the job. Firstly you choose your selectize element `$('.someclass')`, afterwards you choose to select only the input for that element `$('.someclass input')` and finally you trigger the `focus()` function on the element.

Answer (score 0):

I found a easy way:

```
$("#selectid-selectized").focus(
  function () { 
    $("#selectid")[0].selectize.clear(); 
})
```

Comment: Matthew, can you explain your answer a little and prove it from forking the questions JS fiddle. For instance, why would that callback make it work?