# Problems setting HTML5 attribute values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am currently making a list of items of downloaded and not downloaded files with jQuery mobile and Phonegap.

Everything seems to work OK, but I am simply unable to set value to my attribute `data-status`.

I am looping through a list of filenames in a JSON to check if they exists, and this works well. This is what happens for each file:

```
var $li;
$li = $("<li><a href='#' data-status='Not downloaded'>"+val.title+"</a></li>");
```

Then if the file is found on the system:

```
$li.find("a").on("click", function(){ openPdf(val.title); }); // a click handler added
$li.find("a").setAttribute('data-status', 'Downloaded'); // This is where something is wrong.
```

For each file, the $li is appended to the ListView. Then after the whole loop process:

```
$("#linkList")
            .listview({
            autodividers: true,
            autodividersSelector: function (li) {
                        var out = li.find('a').data("status");
                        return out;
                        }
                    }).listview('refresh');
```

So, any ideas why the attribute `data-status` isn't being changed to "Downloaded"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following:

`$li.find("a").data('status', 'Downloaded');`

If you must use `setAttribute`, then go with `attr()`:

`$li.find("a").attr('data-status', 'Downloaded');`

Comment: I tried that one first, but somehow they all end up sorted as "Not downloaded". So it looks like they are not changed.

Comment: that is the correct way to use data attribute with jQuery. you should try on this.

Comment: Added another example using `attr` as an alternative.

Comment: Yes this works. It seems like my problem was elsewhere. I had a `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileSource + val.title + ".pdf", success, fail);` to check for the file and it seems like it was a delay there so the $li was appended before the attribute was set.

Answer (score 2):

```
$li.find("a")
```

return a jQuery object known as the "wrapped set," which is an array-like structure that contains all the selected DOM elements

```
$li.find("a")[0].setAttribute
```

[it contain good description about jQuery Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1302443/894111)