# Difference between $('selector') and $('selector')[0] in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, dom

Assuming i have a `<div class="test" style="width:200px"></div>`,Please consider the following:

```
var m = $('.test')[0];
var $md = $(m);
console.log($md.width()); //200

var o = $('.test');
console.log(o.width());  // 200


console.log(m);   // <div class="test" style="width:200px">
console.log($md);  // Object{ context: <div.test> ..... } 
console.log(o);   // Object{ length:1 , ..... }
```

Basically i can apply the `width` method on either `var $md` or `var o`, so what's the difference between the 1st and 2nd way if the output is the same?
 I see that both `md` and `o` are objects, but in the console output they not exactly the same, how do they differ? thanks.

Comment: `$('selector')` gives you an array of matching elements and `$('selector')[0]` will give you first element from an array

Comment: one is DOM object other is not but using `$()` you turned it to DOM object as well so that will make them the same

Comment: @Curiousdev `$('selector')` returns not array, but array-like object

Comment: @Curiousdev, it returns a `node` list.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai not acually :) `NodeLIst` is DOM class supported by browsers natively  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList but jQuery returns its own object

Comment: @Curiousdev your comment is misleading. Like Curious noted, it returns the the DOM object of the first matching element, NOT the first jQuery object in the collection. If you want the first jQuery object in a collection, use `$('selector').eq(0);`

Comment: @Curious you might be right it's very controversial topic though what  $('selector') do is just searches through the DOM for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new jQuery object may be you are right..

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai  you might be right it's very controversial topic though what $('selector') do is just searches through the DOM for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new jQuery object may be you are right..

Comment: There is nothing controversial about this. `$('.test')[0];` and `$('.test')` intentionally return very different things. They are in no way interchangeable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302428/what-does-jquery-actually-return

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you get the first element matched selector, it returns plain js instance.

```
var m = $('.test')[0];
```

Here you wrap it in a jQuery object again.

```
var $md = $(m);
```

Since [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) method return width of the first element in set there is no difference between approach, until you've got a multiple `.test` elements on a page and want to change them like this:

```
 $('.test').width(100)
```

This code will set the width of each `.test` element on a page to 100px.

But this continue to change only first matched element in a set:

```
 var el = $('.test')[0];
 $(el).width(100);
```

---

There are synthetic examples based on your code, i think it's better to write this way:

```
$('.test').first().width(100);
```

or

```
$('.this:first').width(100);
```