# Make all options enabled in select element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown with a few disabled options. And I want make all options enabled.

This is **html**:

```
<select id="selectId">
    <option value="JavaScript" disabled="">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Angular">Angular</option>
    <option value="Backbone" disabled="">Backbone</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var select = $("#selectId");
select.find("option").each(function(index, item) {
  item.attr('disabled',false);
});
```

But I get an error: TypeError: item.attr is not a function. What's wrong here?

Comment: Use `$(this).attr('disabled',false);` in loop or just ` $("#selectId option").removeAttr("disabled");` without any loop!

Comment: @PrashantShirke Yes, it's working and also $(item).attr('disabled',false); Just curious, why my initial version is not working?

Comment: `attr` is jquery method so works only on jquery objects. `item` in `.each` is DOM element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove disabled attribute using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626517/remove-disabled-attribute-using-jquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to alter properties (`disabaled` is a property not an attribute) is to use `prop`, see [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr):

```js
$("#selectId option").prop('disabled', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectId">
    <option value="JavaScript" disabled="">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Angular">Angular</option>
    <option value="Backbone" disabled="">Backbone</option>
</select>
```

You can set [`.attr('disabled',false);`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13626608/542251) but this doesn't work on [every HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626517/how-to-remove-disabled-attribute-using-jquery/13626608#comment91722641_13626608). The correct way to remove properties (disabled is a property and not an attribute) is `prop`.

Your `each` also doesn't return a jquery object, it returns a vanilla DOM element, hence the `TypeError: item.attr is not a function.`. `item` does not have a `attr` function because it's not a jquery object.

Comment: Neither is working: TypeError: $(...).prop is not a function

Comment: Have you loaded jquery? What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: FYI `disabled="false"` makes sense!

Comment: @PrashantShirke no it doesn't, disabled is a property, it's usage is implied by its' existance or lack of. The equals part is never read. An option is either `<option disabled />` or `<option />`. `<option disabled="false" />` is invalid HTML (though most browsers will handle it, kinda)

Comment: See [Correct value for disabled attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961526/correct-value-for-disabled-attribute)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var select = $("#selectId");
select.find("option:disabled").prop("disabled",false)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectId">
    <option value="JavaScript" disabled="">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Angular">Angular</option>
    <option value="Backbone" disabled="">Backbone</option>
</select>
```

1. No need to iterate.
2. Use selector `:disabled` to select all disabled
3. Use `.prop()` to set to enabled

Answer (score 1):

Your initial version is not working since your selector `select.find("option")` returns a [jQuery object known as the "wrapped set"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302428/what-does-jquery-actually-return), which is an array-like structure that [contains all the selected DOM elements](http://docs.jquery.com/Core). This elements are not jQuery objects so [`attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) will not work and that is why you get `TypeError: item.attr is not a function`.

**UPDATE:** For @Liam, this will work with `.attr('disabled', false)` as you can see from the code below. But I still prefer [using `.prop()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626517/remove-disabled-attribute-using-jquery).

```js
var select = $("#selectId");
select.find("option").each(function(index, item) {
  $(item).attr('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectId">
    <option value="JavaScript" disabled="">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Angular">Angular</option>
    <option value="Backbone" disabled="">Backbone</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Also the syntax for `attr` is wrong, you can't set the `disabled` attribute to false.

Comment: @Liam I can, this is working: $(item).attr('disabled',false);

Comment: [Turns out this is a thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13626608/542251), though this is incorrect usage...

Comment: @Liam yes, it is better to use `prop()`

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery-3.5.1, this worked for me:

```
$("#selectId").find("option:disabled").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score -1):

This one should work fine :)

```js
$("#selectId option").each((i,items)=>{
        $(items).attr('disabled',false)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectId">
        <option value="JavaScript" disabled="">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="Angular">Angular</option>
        <option value="Backbone" disabled="">Backbone</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Wow!!! it seems that i messed something up in a terrible way. Maybe some one can explain the down vote and prevent me in doing other people more harm then necessary

Comment: --> According to my terrible answer